Qt gif is not valid
I created a .gif file https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wHorsxHpfXZc2xm-iEuMG4McsOT-f85/view?usp=sharing
I am adding the git with help of QMovie
    QLabel* progressIcon = new QLabel(this);
    QMovie* progressMovie = new QMovie(dirPath + "Progress_Animation.gif"); // path is correct
    progressIcon->setMovie(progressMovie);
    progressIcon->setFixedSize(18, 18);
    progressIcon->show();
    progressMovie->start(); 
    if (!progressMovie->isValid()) {
        qDebug() << "MOVIE is NOT valid"; // SEE THIS LOG
    } else {
        qDebug() << "MOVIE is valid";
    }

I  read this question GIF animation in Qt
and added qgif.dll to the folder with my .exe file but it didn't help
What is wrong in my code?

"and added qgif.dll to the folder with my .exe" - this is wrong. The correct folder is written in the link you posted.

If it's not a path issue then its version specific, on my machine (win10 qt 5.15.2 mingw64 8) it prints "MOVIE is valid" and shows animated gif as it should. What qt version and compiler do you use?

Please use QDir(path).filePath(name) instead of path + name

What qDebug() << QImageReader::supportedImageFormats(); prints?

When you use relative path application builds real path based on current working directory, which depending on circumstances can be anything, you assume it to be your source directory or directory that exe located in, and your assumption is wrong. It might be other way around, it might be a root of shadow build.
Try this:
QDir dir(".");
qDebug() << dir.absolutePath();
qDebug() << QFile("Progress_Animation.gif").exists();

Use absolute path
QString path = QDir(qApp->applicationDirPath()).filePath("Progress_Animation.gif");
QMovie* progressMovie = new QMovie(path);


Thank you, but it didn't help
file exists (updated my question)
